# Jhipster override entity (keep existant + add behaviour)

Tags: jhipster

I like the jhipster entity generator. 
I often get to change my model and regen all entities.

I wish to keep the generated stuff and override for my needs.

On angular side, it is quite easy to create a new service extending the default entity service to do my stuff.

On java side, it is more complicated.
For example, I override src/main/java/xxx/web/rest/xxxResource.java with src/main/java/xxx/web/rest/xxxOverrideResource.java

- I have to comment @RestController in xxxResource.java. I tried to give it a different bundle name from the overrided class but it is not sufficient : @RestController("xxxResource")
- In xxxOverrideResource.java, I have to change all @xxxMapping() to different paths
- In xxxOverrideResource.java, I have to change all method names
  This allow me to keep the CRUD UI and API, and overload it using another MappingPath.

Some code to make it more visual. Here is the generated xxxResource.java

```
/**
 * REST controller for managing WorldCommand.
 */
// Commented to prevent bean dupplicated error.
// @RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class WorldCommandResource {
    private final WorldCommandService worldCommandService;

    public WorldCommandResource(WorldCommandService worldCommandService) {
        this.worldCommandService = worldCommandService;
    }

    @PutMapping("/world-commands")
    @Timed
    public ResponseEntity<WorldCommand> updateWorldCommand(@Valid @RequestBody WorldCommand worldCommand)
            throws URISyntaxException {
        log.debug("REST request to update WorldCommand : {}", worldCommand);
        ...
    }
```

Here is my overloaded version : xxxOverrideResource.java

```
/**
 * REST controller for managing WorldCommand.
 */
@RestController("WorldCommandOverrideResource")
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class WorldCommandOverrideResource extends WorldCommandResource {
    private final WorldCommandOverrideService worldCommandService;

    public WorldCommandOverrideResource(WorldCommandOverrideService worldCommandService) {
        super(worldCommandService);
        log.warn("USING WorldCommandOResource");
        this.worldCommandService = worldCommandService;
    }

    @PutMapping("/world-commands-override")
    @Timed
    public ResponseEntity<WorldCommand> updateWorldCommandOverride(@Valid @RequestBody WorldCommand worldCommand)
            throws URISyntaxException {
        throw new RuntimeException("WorldCommand updating not allowed");
    }
```

With the xxxResource overrided, it is easy to override the xxxService and xxxRepository by constructor injection.

I feel like I am over thinking it. As it is not an external component but code from a generator, maybe the aim is to use the tool to write less code and then do the changes you need.

Also, I fear this overriding architecture will prevent me from creating abstract controller if needed.

1. Do you think keeping the original generated code is a good pratice or I should just make my changes in the generated class and be carefull when regenerating an entity ?
2. Do you know a better way to override a Spring controller ?

Comment: Thank you Gael for the talk show link. Devoxx guy had exactly the same questioning.
If you are in a hurry, the video says keeping the generated code is useful if :
- there is some business value of the generated UI
- if you regenerate entities often.
- to easily upgrade jhipster version (or add new features of the generator).

About my question on the RestResource extension, he also had to change the /api to another path.

I liked the list of improvements of jhipster he suggested in the end. (a few seems to be present in current version).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach looks like the side-by-side approach described here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9WVpwIUEty0

I often found that the generated REST API is only useful for managing data in a backoffice and I usually write a complete separate API with different endpoints, authorizations and DTOs that is consumed by mobile or end-users. So I don't see much value in overriding REST controllers, after all they are supposed to be quite thin with as little business logic as possible.

You must also consider how long you want to keep this compatibility with generated code. As your app grows in complexity you might want to refactor your code and organize it around feature packages rather than by technical packages (repository, rest controllers, services, ...). For many reasons, sooner or later the way the generated code is setup will get in your way, so I would not put too much effort into this compatibility goal that has no real business value especially when you know that the yearly released major version may break it because of changes in the generator itself or more likely because of changes in underlying frameworks.